# How can I initialise items in an array without knowing their type?

Tags: c#, arrays, interface, constructor

If I am passed an instance of a class which implements an interface, I do not necessarily know the exact type. If I want to create an array of this class (whatever it may be), I can do so like this:

```
IWhatever[] ArrayOfClass = (IWhatever[])Array.CreateInstance(InstanceOfClass.GetType(), length);
```

As long as InstanceOfClass is an instance of a class which implements IWhatever, this works.

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to initialise the members of the array. I thought `new IWhatever()` might work, but it doesn't.

How do I construct the members of array?

Comment: Array variance is bad, please don't use it EVER!

Comment: Why don't you just use `new IWhatever[length]` for making the array itself?  That would be able to hold objects of the same type as `InstanceOfClass` has.

Comment: Ben Voigt is correct on how to create the arrray, but to add items you will have to use a class that implements the interface. Many people like to use a Factory method to make these, but I find that kind of tedious and just use the regular constructors where I need them (unless a lot of computations are required to call the constructor, then I shallow my pride and use a factory)

Comment: @BenVoigt Don't know why I didn't think of that! Makes it much simpler. Still, populating the array remains a problem as the other Ben points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to initialize each member to an instance of some class which implements the interface.

If you wanted the same type as `InstanceOfClass`, and if that type has a default constructor, you could use something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<ArrayOfClass.Length;++i)
{
    ArrayOfClass[i] = (IWhatever)Activator.CreateInstance(InstanceOfClass.GetType());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a factory method to the interface.   The factory method will create an instance
of the correct specific type, which you assign as the array based on its generic type.